# Insert timestamp into table

Tags: mysql, singlestore

We are working on MemSQL database and I want to insert time-series data into a table. MemSQL uses MySQL flavour as a query language to query database. I am using the standard MySQL function: `Date_sub()` which is running into an error message:

```
create table simpletest (edate timestamp, name varchar(20));

insert into simpletest values ("DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)", 'hi');
```

Should I be using a different function to insert data for the last hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MemSQL doesn't support arbitrary expressions inside of `insert` statements as of MemSQL v5 (only literal constants).  This limitation will be removed in the next release.

The best workaround is to write the query as an `insert .. select` instead:

```
INSERT INTO simpletest SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR), 'hi';
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will probably write the qry as an insert!!

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want quotes around "DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)", since then the whole thing is a string.

Comment: Actually, tried that in the first place but no luck So, I tried quotes which I was sure would send a string to the engine. As I mentioned above, I am inserting data in Memsql.

Comment: Yes, you and Adam are correct - my mistake is I was not testing MemSQL 5. I have edited my answer to correct that.